# Data empty in jQuery.get() callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.get("http://localhost/test.php", (function(data){
    alert(data);
}))
```

The alert is empty. I'm new to this, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Help?

Comment: What code is in your test.php page?

Comment: Have you tried just `$.get("test.php", ...)` ? What does the PHP file look like?

Comment: What is a get request to localhost/test.php supposed to return?

Comment: also you should have a semicolon at the very end of that statement, no?

Comment: @Darragh Enright: No. Semicolons are optional.

Comment: Okay, it seems it works with a file:// url. (html file is outside of the webserver dir). Anything else, localhost, random internet text files, doesn't work. @Felix Kling @Andy_Vulhop it's simply <?php echo "test"; ?> but it fails with a text file too.

Comment: It **does** work with a `file://` URL but **not** `http://`? I smell same origin policy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **does** work with a `file://` URL but **not** `http://`? I smell **[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)**.

Are you opening the file with the jQuery in your browser via a `file://` URL then trying to fetch via `http://`? Because your protocol and host have to match when you do Ajax.

Make sure that you're opening the file in your browser as `http://localhost/index.php` and **not** `file://localhost/index.php`. Then you should be able to fetch that file via `http://localhost/test.php`.

Comment: Good call, ran into this issue myself today. Had a small HTML file sitting locally (not web server) that has some JS to continuously refresh a DIV with remote HTML content.  Was tearing my hear out - the HTTP URL worked fine in the browser but F12 Dev Tools showed a 0 byte result from my code and not useful info describing why.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're not telling the code to run? Try putting it in `$(document).ready()` with

```
$(function() {
  $.get("http://localhost/test.php", function(data){
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

If you type http://locahost/test.php in your browser, do you get any data back?

There is no difference whether jquery gets the url or you do, the result should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Does test.php  actually output something?

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What is the mime-type of the response?

[The doc says](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

> The success callback function is
>   passed the returned data, which will
>   be an *XML root element, text string,
>   JavaScript file, or JSON object,
>   depending on the MIME type of the
>   response.* It is also passed the text
>   status of the response.

So depending on the datatype of the data parameter to your callback, the alert may be trying to show you an object that doesn't translate readily to a string.

Answer (score -1):

The callback function should be the third parameter to $.get:

```
 $.get("http://localhost/test.php", {}, (function(data){
     alert(data);
 }))
```

Comment: That does not matter. You can pass the callback as second parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, solved it: Works when the html file is in the webserver dir and called from localhost, doesn't work when the html is file://. This is inconvenient, but oh well. (it seems I can't mark my own answer as the solution until 2 days.)

Comment: read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533934/jquery-why-wont-this-work/3534366#3534366 which is a real answer